# Breaker vs Wire Size

Tags: electrical

I have a 60 amp 208 single phase circuit using 4 AGW Aluminum wire 75-100 feet away from panel.
I need a 30 amp 208 single phase circuit for an expresso machine demo.
Can I just change out the 60 amp breaker with a 30 and use for the day or will the larger wire size not be safe.

Comment: I take it this 208V circuit is derived from two hot phases on a 208Y/120 three phase system?

Answer (score 1):

Having larger wire is ok by changing to a smaller breaker you are protecting the coffee maker, this is fine in code just make sure the new outlet is rated for aluminum wire.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem will be in connecting the larger conductors to the devices designed for smaller ones. You may have to use a "pigtail" arrangement, but that means lots of room in the box.